# cursor.execute() returning empty list when used with parametrized query(python,sqlite)

Tags: python, sqlite

when i use this code:

```py
 def recherche(case,value='*'):
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        if value == '*':
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY ID;")
        else:
            value="%" + str(value) + "%"
            p=(case,value)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE ? LIKE ? ORDER BY ID;",p)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return result
```

result returns as an empty list
on the other hand if i use this:

```py
 def recherche(case,value='*'):
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        if value == '*':
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY ID;")
        else:
            value=str(value)
            p=(case,value)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE " + case + " LIKE '%" + value + "%' ORDER BY ID;")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return result
```

the values are returned properly.
From what i understood using the first method is more optimised but it doesnt work for me at all.

Comment: Is `case` supposed to hold a column name? Those have to be directly present in a query; you can't use parameters for identifiers.

Comment: yes `case` is a column name,is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: @stovfl it doesnt matter since the whole thing gets sent as 1 string,also the quotes block the `?` so it returns the error :`Incorrect number of bindings`

Comment: Use your second approach.

Comment: @TarikAmri: The `?` is for data substitution only. If you want variable field names you have to use Python `str` substitution like.  `.format(...` or `+ fieldname +`.

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE ?` should be:

```
LIKE '?'
```